# Database Multiple Table Query and Display Results

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello everyone I am using codeigniter to build a Project Management System.

I have a function in my model to display a project and the tasks that are associated with it. The $projectId = 1 is for testing purposes only.

```
function getAllProjects($projectId = 1)
 {

  $this->db->select('*');    
  $this->db->from('projects');
  $this->db->where('projects.projectId', $projectId);
  $this->db->join('projectTasks', 'projects.projectId = projectTasks.projectId');
  $this->db->join('tasks', 'projectTasks.taskId = tasks.taskId');
  $projects = $this->db->get();
  return $projects;
}
```

then in my view I have it display the results

```
<?php if($projects->num_rows() > 0): ?>
  <table width="100%">
    <?php foreach($projects->result() as $p): ?>
      <tr>

        <td><?php echo $p->projectId; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $p->projectName; ?></td>
        <?php foreach($projects->result() as $g): ?>
             <td><?php echo $g->taskName; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $g->taskHours; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $g->taskCost; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>No projects at this time.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which returns this

```
  ID - Project Name - Task Name - Task Hours - Task Cost (**to show you what field is what**)
  1 The Range 702   Contact Form      10         100            Custom Logo Desgin  10  100 Custom Login From   5   75
  1 The Range 702   Contact Form      10         100            Custom Logo Desgin  10  100 Custom Login From   5   75
  1 The Range 702   Contact Form      10         100            Custom Logo Desgin  10  100 Custom Login From   5   75
```

Can someone please advise me on how to make it so it only displays the project info once and then each task that is associated to the project. Right now for every task that is associated with the project it lists the project and all the tasks it again.

**Tables**

```
 -----------------------
 |       projects      |
 -----------------------
 |  projectId          | (Primary)
 |  projectName        |
 |  projectHours       |
 |  projectDeadline    |
 |  projectStartDate   |
 |  projectTasks       |
 |  projectUsers       |
 |  projectNotes       |
 |                     |
 -----------------------

 -----------------------
 |     projectTasks    |
 -----------------------
 |  projectTasksId     | (Primary)
 |  projectId          | (FK project->projectId)
 |  taskId             | (FK tasks->taskId)
 |                     |
 -----------------------

 --------------------
 |      tasks       |
 --------------------
 |  taskId          | (Primary)
 |  taskName        |
 |  taskHours       |
 |  taskCost        |
 |                  |
 --------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think Jorge Campos solution was close it won't prevent the tasks from being listed out multiple times.

```
   <?php $ProjectId = ''; ?>
      <?php if($projects->num_rows() > 0): ?>
        <table width="100%">
          <?php foreach($projects->result() as $p): ?>
            <tr>
              <?php if ($ProjectId != $p->projectId) { ?>
              <td><?php echo $p->projectId; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $p->projectName; ?></td>

                <?php foreach($projects->result() as $g): ?>
                    <td><?php echo $g->taskName; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $g->taskHours; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $g->taskCost; ?></td>
               <?php endforeach; ?>

             <?php } ?>
       <?php $ProjectId = $p->projectId; ?>

            </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
      <?php else: ?>
        <p>No projects at this time.</p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

This solution will make it so the information is only displayed once for each projectId.

Comment: I put that code into my view and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to store the project id for each iteration then you compare with the actual project id and if it is different you show the project info. Something like this.

```
<?php
 $beforeProject = '';
 foreach($projects->result() as $p):
?>
    <td><?php if ($beforeProject != $p->projectId) { echo $p->projectId; } ?></td>

     //rest of code

   <?php $beforeProject = $p->projectId; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```